# Muting Certain Frequencies in Windows 10 Audio

Tags: windows, audio

Is there a way to mute certain frequencies in Windows 10? Like actually disable a certain frequency, or lower it so much it's nearly inaudible? I'd like to play games with the gunfire sounds muted or lowered b/c the sound gives me a headache, but I don't want to sacrifice the rest of the games' soundscape. Is this even possible I wonder? I have Peace equalizer installed but I don't think its capable of that.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You might do better with a compressor rather than just EQ. The gunfire effects will likely share frequencies with much of the other audio - it will just be louder.

Look at something from [VB Audio](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm) for starters - all donationware so you can try them all out for free. There's Voicemeeter, Banana & Potato [yes, all rather silly names but don't let that put you off;) each more complex than the last, but each with EQ & compression.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found a compressor and tried it out and it works quite well.